# Moderators Pro-Tempore Nomination

Tags: discussion, pro-tem-moderators

Every beta site has [moderators pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) until it graduates. I realize this site is still just out of private beta, but, when will we nominate our moderators pro tempore? Is there a typical time after private beta when these are chosen?

### Change of plan...

This question will serve as the nomination area. To nominate someone, simply create an answer with the name of the person and why you feel they should be moderator. Self-nominations are fine. Vote for the candidates you believe would be good moderators.

Comment: Now is as good of time as any to start nominating people. Just make it clear in the question body that it's one nomination per answer so people can vote on them. Remember, downvotes work different on meta. It just means you disagree with the nomination and doesn't affect reputation at all.

Comment: Anyone wishing to nominate someone, or self-nominate, should follow the template below.

Comment: Should Luke's question be edited so that it follows jmort253's suggestion and acts as the voting quest for Moderators?

Comment: We might as well.

Comment: We need at least one more nomination (normally there are three pro-temp mods).

Comment: There can be more nominations than 3 though, even though there are only 3 slots. The names submitted here will help guide the community management team in selecting the 3 people who can fill this role.

Comment: That's why I said *at least* one more.

Comment: Not expressing an opinion on any of the nominees so far (they all look to have some plus points to me) but I do note they're all in the same(ish) time-zone and continent (US/Canada). To my mind it would be good to have (at least one of) (say) a European and an Australian, if we can find them without compromising the qualities needed for a moderator.

Comment: My answer has been converted to a comment, and I have been referred to the faq as explanation, but the faq don't explain why! What do I do now, as I believe my point is important, just not to a single nomination? Hoping Luke with his moderation experience can help.

Comment: It looks like one of the inter-site mods (such as [Robert Cartaino](http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/31/robert-cartaino)) converted it to a comment, as you know. The reasoning was probably that someone flagged it as "not an answer" because I had previously changed the question to a nomination area. It is a good point though. If something goes wrong, and all the mods are asleep, it won't get any action for up to ten hours. I completely agree. I've upvoted it to make it more obvious. However, if you want to make sure more people read it, consider creating another meta post.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - Fortiter is in Australia. There are a few others in that region as well.

Comment: @jmort253 Noted, although Fortiter hadn't been nominated when I commented.

Comment: If you can think of anyone else @ColeValleyGirl, consider adding them. ;)  Check out the [List of Users](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users), as some people list where they're located. Good luck! :)

Comment: Is it normal to have so many declinations?

Comment: @Luke, I'm not surprised, given that some of us are still settling down and exploring our comfort levels wrt to the "tone" of the site. Moderating at such an early stage is likely to be more work than it will be later. (Does Forming-Storming-Norming-Performing ring any bells? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuckman%27s_stages_of_group_development) Also, some of our most active users have major commitments elsewhere. I'm not nominating myself for exactly that reason.

Comment: How about Gene Golovchinsky for mod? I don't have time to write up a nomination now, but if someone else wants to, I'll vote for him.

Comment: @Luke - Don't worry about whether it's normal or not. Some people just don't have the time. I personally spend way too much time on Stack Exchange as it is, and being a moderator on another site would make it that much harder to balance my time in other activities... ;) Plus, once the site graduates, the people here could run in the elections, assuming their workload allows it at a later date!

Comment: is it appropriate to try to get moderators from the different communities of genealogy? One flavor of community is what country. Another is what culture (eg US doesn't necessarily mean expert in African American). Another is amateur vs professional genealogist. I'm sure there are more. I don't know what the current mix is but I would think we'd want diversity. Of course we need to get membership diversity in these communities first so my comment might be longer term.

Comment: @Duncan - Balance is definitely a good thing, but not a requirement. The main goal is to get people who are patient and fair, and who are willing to help guide the community to work through the issues of defining the site. It doesn't matter what community or country they're from.

Answer (score 11):

### Nomination for GeneJ [Decision Deferred]

On a new beta site, patience is an important quality, perhaps more so than any other quality listed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) -- a must read for any potential moderator.

[GeneJ](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/7) is someone who I believe demonstrates this quality. I've seen this person leave many helpful, constructive comments on the site to help people improve Q&A, and she's also willing to learn from others. Additionally, she's passionate about Genealogy, judging from the 1K rep earned so far on the site.

This person also hangs out in the [Roots](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6003/roots) chat room. At least one of the moderators appointed should be a regular in the chat room, if not all of them.

GeneJ is also the [top editor for the month](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors), which means this person is skilled at fixing problems, which is a great skill to have when faced with a post that could either be edited and improved.

---

Traditionally, people nominated as moderators should accept, or kindly reject, the nomination by editing the post. I've marked this as community wiki so Gene can edit.

---

**Status of nomination:** Nominee is honored; accepts; hoping for company. Thank you.

Comment: I am happy to accept this nomination ... and assume others will follow?

Comment: This nomination is a no-brainer.

Comment: @GeneJ Don't forget to edit the status of the answer.

Comment: Until the community works out the issues of what makes a good genealogical query in this forum, it would be premature for anyone to step into this role.

Comment: @GeneJ: Don't give up. I knew we'd reach this "hump" in the beta where we seem to be getting a bit stuck. We need new people to come to the site and start a new round of questions. This morning, I sent out a few emails to some significant people to try to drum up some new interest. But it would be nice if others would help with this. See: http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/coordinating-publicity

Comment: @GeneJ: Also, you sent me an email a while back with a few people who you thought would be good moderators. Why not nominate them here?

Comment: @lkessler Thanks, I take your comments to heart. As per my comment, seems premature to ask folks to commit before we can better describe what the context of this great new forum. It will come together, just needs a little time.

Comment: @GeneJ - As far as moderator nominations or any issues with the site go for that matter, the more that can be discussed in public, the better engaged the community will become. I encourage meta, with the exceptions of cases where user privacy is concerned, like moderators discussing people issues with another moderator.

Comment: @GeneJ - You should reconsider. To step into a moderator role, you don't need to have all the answers. Just the criteria in [Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Comment: @GeneJ - Then if it's premature, maybe you could change your "declined" to "decision deferred".

Comment: @GeneJ - For sure! The point of the moderator roles is precisely to help work through these community issues. SE employees can't do it because they don't know Genealogy. We need real genealogists who understand the issues this community faces. I *really* think you'd do a good job and encourage you to reconsider. ;)

Comment: @GeneJ I think that your approach tends to be more inclusive, broad minded and encouraging. These qualities are strongly needed in this role, especially to counter balance some long time or hard edged SE'ers. Your voice is greatly appreciated here and deserves to have some weight behind it.

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout You are so kind. (And, back at you!)

Comment: @GeneJ At this early stage in the site, it is essential for there to be some kind of moderators. But they won't be some decree that enforces some standards, especially ones not yet figured. They are normal users of the site who are elevated to be able to help guide discussions and to police issues that rise on the site. Think of it less as a commitment to a job, and more a volunteer position that stands up and helps direct the growth - they will help create the guidelines not just for the community, but for themselves. Does this address any of your concerns?

Comment: @GeneJ - The 'title' of your nomination says 'Decision Deferred' but I imply from the text you'd be willing to accept. Should you update the title?

Answer (score 9):

### Nomination for [Luke](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/56/luke) [Accepted]

Quite necessary to moderatorship is experience. Although I have never been a moderator yet, I have well over [6400 reputation](http://stackexchange.com/users/1119942/luke) across the SE network with 20 silver badges and over 115 bronze badges. I actively participate in metas on two other beta sites (History and Music), ELU, and [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/192187/luke). Even on this site, I am the the [third most active](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) user in meta and have voted the [second most times](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters) there.

On the main site, although my rep is not outstanding, I have made the third most edits and have voted the fourth most times there. Across the network, I have raised over 100 helpful flags. <del>I am currently trying to get a link to GFH SE in the History SE FAQ to promote GFH SE there (currently, the link still goes to the Area51 page).</del> *Done. History SE FAQ now has link to GFH SE.*

I also have experience dealing with tough users. I can spot our new problem user at twenty paces, yet I know when is the right time to take action and when patience should be exerted. I know when suspension is necessary and have successfully lobbied for the suspension of users multiple times. On the other hand, I help new users to formulate good questions that follow the SE guidelines and format.

Because of such, I have reviewed the most first-posts on [GFH SE](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats) (over twice as many as the runner-up), [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats), and [Music SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats). I have done the most reviews in six other queues across the network and have completed over 430 review tasks in the last 41 days.

---

As an avid and experienced Stack Exchanger, I would like to nominate myself for Moderator Pro Tempore.

Comment: I love your resume Luke. You have my vote.

Answer (score 7):

### Nomination for [**lKessler**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/29/lkessler) [Declined]

[LKessler](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/29/lkessler) is patient, respectful and helpful.  His presence is known in the Main, Meta and Chat room sections.  He is never sarcastic.  Something else I’ve noticed is that he has been giving others a chance to participate by not answering questions immediately himself.  I feel an important moderator trait is encouraging participation on the site.

Louis is an experienced 4 year member of Stack Exchange with a total rep over 10,000.   He is a genealogist, genealogy software developer and operates a [GenSoft Reviews site](http://www.gensoftreviews.com/).  His knowledge of both the ‘nuts and bolts’ of Stack Exchange and his experience in genealogy are essential during Beta.  He is also fantastic at publicity – recruiting 100 members to this site when it was still in its infancy at Area51.  As already noted by others, this is an international site and it would be helpful to have one non-US moderator.

---

**Status of nomination** - Nominee appreciates the recognition, but respectfully declines.

Comment: @lkessler I hope you have time for this!

Comment: +1 ti lkessler! I was going to nominate him if no one else did. The 100 referrals is awesome, and he's already working in meta on ways to encourage people to help promote the site.

Comment: Thanks Jeni, Justin and jmort. I appreciate the kind words and the nomination. However at this point, I must respectfully decline being a moderator. I have effectively taken off two months from the development of my genealogy software Behold, and I need to get back to it. That program will be my next big contribution to the genealogy community. That said, I still will be here at the GFH site, contributing and helping out where possible, as well as helping to promote and advertise this site with the goal of ensuring it gets out of beta and becomes permanent.

Answer (score 7):

### Self-nomination for [ColeValleyGirl](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/104/colevalleygirl)

I haven't experience on StackExchange other than on this site, but I do have business experience in Mentoring and Coaching and Change Management that should help me do a good job for the community if I'm accepted — and to recognise and acknowledge when I've made mistakes.

I'm passionate about doing my amateur family history research to professional standards, and am always eager to improve my skills and knowledge, but I recognise that those who come here will have widely differing levels of experience as well as standards that they're happy to work to. We have to be welcoming to everyone without diluting the quality of the content here if we're to build a reputation as one of the best places to come for genealogy answers. Which means coaching, cajoling, judicious editing... and sometimes saying: this doesn't belong here in its current form and this is why and what you can do to improve it.

As a community we're still very young, and we haven't reached a consensus yet on what our community standards are; we need to get our pro-tem moderators in place to help that process along. I originally said I was too busy to volunteer, but I want to see this community succeed so I'll make the time it needs if I'm appointed.

Comment: Yes. (and yes, yes ... because I have to add more characters in order to post this.)

Comment: You would do a great job! +1 +1 +1. Thanks for volunteering! :)

Comment: You have my vote also. I'm sure you'll do a great job with your friendly and helpful approach, which is what is needed at this stage.

Answer (score 4):

### Nomination for [jmort253](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/71/jmort253) [Declined]

jmort is active on many SE sites with over 1k rep on 8 sites and a total of 48k. He is a moderator on [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/34/) and has demonstrated his moderator knowledge in his many excellent posts here on meta. In fact, he is the [most active user](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users) here on meta. That has been very influential in the formation of this community.

Despite only having 353 rep here, he has an impressive [collection of badges](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/71/jmort253?tab=badges) which means he is active in all aspects of the site and his work is quality.

I imagine that him already being a moderator will make it likely that he isn't offered the position or doesn't accept, but he has my vote anyways. I trust his ability to help lead our community.

---

**Status of nomination:**

Thank you for the nomination, but I feel I must decline. There are many members on this site with great leadership skills *and* knowledge of Genealogy *and* who are really passionate about the field. I'd much prefer to see one of those individuals step forward and self-nominate instead.

You don't really need Stack Exchange experience to be a pro temp moderator, you just have to be willing to listen and learn along with everyone else, exercise restraint in tough situations, and lead by example by teaching and guiding the many new users that will show up.

I still plan to contribute to this site as a beta user, of course.

Answer (score 3):

### Nomination for [Fortiter](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/70/fortiter?tab=summary) [Declined]

**Status of nomination:** *Declined*

Comment: I'd add, as @ColeValleyGirl said, "I do note they're all in the same(ish) time-zone and continent (US/Canada). To my mind it would be good to have (at least one of) (say) a European and an Australian." Fortiter (who's from Down Under) fits the bill. Having mods around the world rather than one locale ensures around-the-clock moderation.

Comment: Readers of meta will no doubt have detected that I have some concerns as to the nature and direction of the site. Under the circumstances, it would not be appropriate for me to offer to undertake the significant responsibilities outlined.

Comment: @Fortiter I have been active in meta and was surprised to see you say this. Even if it is true, I don't think it disqualifies you from being a mod. Disagreements are not inherently bad.

Comment: We could beg? Pretty please!

Comment: @Fortiter - unless you don't have the time, I think you should reconsider.  (I'm also have trouble figuring out your concerns about the site's direction even though I read meta)  As someone who is still struggling to ask questions correctly, I find your comments helpful & I know from your questions and blog that you are very knowledgeable in the field

Comment: @Fortiter Noting your recent excellent answers and edits to first time posts, plus the fact that you are over 5,000 rep (wow!), remind me again why you've declined _temporary_ moderator status? You seem to have the interest, skill and decorum to fill the bill. Please reconsider.

Comment: I second what @CanadianGirlScout says. You're already doing a lot of the things a pro temp moderator would do, and you'd do a good job. You should seriously reconsider as the community needs leaders in this role.

Answer (score 1):

### Nomination for [Duncan](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/157/duncan)

Qualifications:

1. [#12](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) in all time reputation
2. [#6](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users) in activity on meta
3. Participated in [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/27657/)
4. One of 9 users to be awarded the [Convention](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/badges/68/convention) badge which means:

   - He is active in forming the community
   - We tend to agree with his opinions
5. I haven't seen him get into an disputes or react harshly to incompetence, which means he's patient and level-headed.

---

**Status of nomination:** Pending

I am undecided on accepting. I feel strongly genealogy.se needs representation from all the groups of stakeholders, including what I'll call the 'casual genealogist' - a group I fall into. However that means I do not have the time to devote to this that a moderator probably needs to. Let me research some more on what exactly it means to accept. I've read [moderators pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) and am still not certain what it means from a time commitment (both hours/week and response time). Because I hold a full-time-double-plus job in a totally unrelated field (information security), I'm not sure I can do it justice. However I know we need moderators. Seems we were supposed to have 3-4 by the 2-week point and we are at day 68 and have none as near as I can tell.

Comment: I think Duncan would represent this community well. +1