# What form do StackExchange town halls take? When is the best time to hold a StackExchange town hall?

Tags: discussion, chat

Are town halls just organized sessions in chat, or are we permitted to hold them in an audio forum (GoToWebinar, etc.).

Are there rules or best practices? Are some topics off limits?

Are there examples of town meetings that have been held too soon or too late? What timing is just right for a town meeting? Is there a reason we would not want to start now holding town meetings on some regular basis?

Comment: What's a town hall meeting in the context of StackExchange?

Comment: As far as I know, they are always held in a chat room created specifically for the town hall chat. Are you thinking of discussing the moderator nominations or on/off-topic or something else?

Comment: @Luke Town halls do tend to be open, but I have been caught of guard by the on/topic off topic issue, so I'd like to hear more on that from the broader community. "Analysis of the questions ..." by ColeValleyGirl is a similar topic.

Comment: Chat is really pretty open. You can pretty much talk about whatever you want. If you want to schedule an event, you might be able to do it yourself. Can't remember if it's mod-only or not. If it is, I'm sure the community team could schedule the event for you.

Comment: The on/off topic issue and the 'what is a good question' issue are two things I'd like to get a better feel of the wider views about.

Comment: I feel like our chat area is a ghost town despite a few of us trying to engage. Why don't you get a discussion going there?

Comment: I've felt like some of the meta banter that has been posted lately would've been better served in chat.

Answer (score 3):

The only event we (the Stack Exchange Team) apply the term "Town Hall Chat" is just prior to a Moderator election where community members can ask the candidates questions. We're still quite a ways off until you [graduate and have a general election](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/).

First we have to find you guys some temporary, [provisional moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/). There's been too few nominations coming from the community and **way too many nominees declining** to get even a temporary moderator staff up and running for this site.

See [**Moderator Pro Tem Nominations**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/moderators-pro-tempore-nomination).

### Having said that…

This is your meta forum and your place [to organize your site's governance](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). If you feel there are issues that can be solved by real-time collaborations, our internal chat rooms are a great place to hold such events. Call them Town Halls or whatever you wish, but these types of organized events are a great way to increase engagement and get things done.

Comment: Thanks much for this information.